# Trigger in subscriber is getting deleted when replication is created

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a table A in publisher database and there is trigger which inserts data into table B when an entry happens in table A. I have the same configuration in subscriber database,
that is Table A, Table B and the trigger. I have done transactional replication for both the DB and after the establishing the replication, trigger in subscriber database is deleted. Please give me the reason why the trigger in subscriber is deleted when the replication is created.

Answer (score 0):

Is your trigger created with the "NOT FOR REPLICATION" option?

Rob